# downloading file from FTP with urllib2.urlopen is too slow

Tags: python, ftp, urllib2

I'm trying to download files from FTP using this code:

```
    with closing(urllib2.urlopen(file_url)) as r:
        with open(dir + '/' + filename, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r, f)
```

I took about 30 secs for a 900KB file! what should I do?
This is one of the files:

```
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/oa_package/00/02/PMC1241068.tar.gz
```

Comment: How are you sure that this is related to urllib2 at all not not related to the connection between your system and the server, some rate limiting or inspecting firewall, a slow server or similar? Did you test it with an alternative client using the same URL, same possible proxy and from __the same machine__ and got consistently faster times with this client and consistently slow download times with urllib2?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your reply, It's not about my connection because I'm running it on a 100MB bandwidth server, on the other side there is Pubmed servers which belongs to National Americal Health Center.

Comment: I've seen slow connections over fast links caused by bad interaction of TCP options on both sides and slowdowns caused by interactions with routers and firewalls. That's why again the question:   Did you test it with an alternative client using the same URL, same possible proxy and from __the same machine__ and got consistently faster times with this client and consistently slow download times with urllib2? I very much doubt that this is related to ftplib.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've tried on that machine using wget command. It took 3 secs. what now?

Comment: Thanks for the test. Your code takes 3..4 seconds on my machine while wget takes about the same time (actually, usually about 0.5..1 seconds more). It would be interesting to look at the lower levels then by doing a packet capture to see if really the download itself makes a difference or the DNS lookup or the startup of the program.

Comment: At https://pastebin.com/wknBBQi7 you'll find a minimal python program and command line to reproduce the problem and get the timing about startup and actual download times without doing a packet capture. Would be interesting to get the result of this from your environment.